# Proving a subset of R is countable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I have a subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}$. I know that given any sequence $(u_n)$ of elements of $V$, $(u_n)$ doesn't converge in $\mathbb{R}$. It seems "obvious" that it implies that $V$ is countable. However I am not familiar with this kind of proofs, and I am not able to write explicitly why the properties of the sequence imply that $V$ is at most countable. Do someone knows which classical theorem we should apply? Or can someone write explicitly the proof ? Thank you.

Comment: Count the elements in each compact $[n,n+1]$.

Comment: ...and apply Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Is there a restriction on the $u_n$?  Do they have to be distinct elements of $V$?  For example, let $x \in V$.  The trivial sequence $u_n = x$ for all $n$ converges to $x \in V \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank to the analysts !-of course they have to be distinct.

Comment: If the answer was helpful you should consider accept it, just saying because you are new to the website and haven't accepted any yet. Take a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers).

Answer (score 4):

Consider how many elements of $V$ can lie in $[-n,n]$. We know that any bounded infinite set in $\mathbb{R}$ has an accumulation point, so $V \cap [-n,n]$ must not be infinite. But $V = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty V \cap [-n,n]$ is then the union of countably many finite sets. Thus $V$ is countable.